# Any disadvantages to single-supply mode?

Tags: microcontroller, power, atmel

I am using the ATMEL ARM SAM4S MCU for a project. It supports a single-supply mode where an internal voltage regulator provides the 1.08-1.32V necessary for VDDCORE and we need only provide 1.62-3.6V to VDDIO.

I'm just interested to know if there is any situation where one might NOT take advantage of this feature and supply the core externally as well?

Comment: Good question, I assume the internal regulator would be linear so main reason would probably be for better efficiency in power critical applications where the hassle is worth it, or if you have a 1.2V odd supply available already.

Comment: It might also be that CPU-intensive operations overload the internal regulator, or increase the heat dissipated inside the chip, and for heavy duty applications and/or high clock rates, an external supply is recommended. The datasheet ought to cover this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason would be for power efficiency. The voltage regulator inside the chip is a linear one, which means that its efficiency is: (VDDCORE/VDDIO). So if your VDDIO is 3.6v, then your efficiency might be only 33%! This is a terrible waste of energy, especially in a battery powered portable device where a long battery life is an important selling point for the device.

Poor power efficiency not only leads to a shorter battery life, it also generates heat. In this case it doesn't seem like much, but it can make all the difference. In a hot environment, that extra heat might push the chip over its specified operating conditions, leading to failure. In some applications, you might have lots of chips, which could create quite a lot of heat. In one application, we had 20 ET1200 chips, all using their internal regulators. Each chip's core uses just 75mA. But 20 chips means 1.5A on the cores, and a total of 1.2W of power dissipated just as wasted heat. The inside of the enclosure got pretty hot.